# Yocto + Qt5 on i.MX6 (FSL Community BSP): xcb dependency for webkit?

Tags: linux, qt5, embedded-linux, yocto

I am studying Yocto (dizzy) and I am trying to prepare an image for a Freescale i.MX6-based system. I started from the [FSL Community BSP](http://freescale.github.io) and then I've included the [meta-qt5](https://github.com/meta-qt5/meta-qt5) layer.

Then I've made some customization in by `local.conf` file, in order to build Qt and exclude X11 and Wayland from the compilation (since I want to use Qt5 throughh EGLFS platform):

```
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES = "debug-tweaks ssh-server-openssh"

IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " gcc g++ binutils libgcc libgcc-dev libstdc++ libstdc++-dev libstdc++-staticdev \
autoconf automake ccache chkconfig glib-networking glibmm \
packagegroup-core-buildessential pkgconfig  \
boost cmake zlib glib-2.0 packagegroup-fsl-tools-testapps git glive \
    ruby \
    cpufrequtils \
    nano \
    gdb \
    gstreamer \
    gst-meta-video \
    gst-fsl-plugin \
    gst-plugins-base-app \
    gst-plugins-base \
    gst-plugins-good \
    gst-plugins-good-rtsp \
    gst-plugins-good-udp \
    gst-plugins-good-rtpmanager \
    gst-plugins-good-rtp \
    gst-plugins-good-video4linux2 \
    openssh-sftp-server \
    packagegroup-fsl-gstreamer \
    packagegroup-fsl-tools-testapps \
    packagegroup-fsl-tools-benchmark \
    imx-vpu \
    imx-test \       
    qtbase-fonts \
    qtbase-plugins \
    qtbase-tools \
    qtbase-examples \
    qtdeclarative \
    qtdeclarative-plugins \
    qtdeclarative-tools \
    qtdeclarative-examples \
    qtdeclarative-qmlplugins \
    qtmultimedia \
    qtmultimedia-plugins \
    qtmultimedia-examples \
    qtmultimedia-qmlplugins \
    qtsvg \
    qtsvg-plugins \
    qtsensors \
    qtimageformats-plugins \
    qtsystems \
    qtsystems-tools \
    qtsystems-examples \
    qtsystems-qmlplugins \
    qtscript \
    qt3d \
    qt3d-examples \
    qt3d-qmlplugins \
    qt3d-tools \
    qtwebkit \
    qtwebkit-examples-examples \
    qtwebkit-qmlplugins \
    qtgraphicaleffects-qmlplugins \
    qtconnectivity-qmlplugins \
    qtlocation-plugins \
    qtlocation-qmlplugins \
    cinematicexperience \
    cairo pango fontconfig freetype pulseaudio dbus \
    alsa-lib alsa-tools alsa-state alsa-utils-alsaconf fsl-alsa-plugins \
    i2c-tools \ 
    strace \
    "

PACKAGECONFIG_remove = " x11 wayland"
DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = " x11 wayland"
```

Everything is fine (issuing `bitbake fsl-image-multimedia-full`): the image is built and I am able to compile and run minimal applications which use Qt on EGLFS platform.

The problem comes when I want to use the QML WebView... If I try to do that at runtime the Qt application exits with the following message:

> root@imx6qsabresd:~# /run/media/sda1/MyTestApp -platform eglfs This
>   application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt
>   platform plugin "xcb".
>
> Available platform plugins are: eglfs, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen.
>
> Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. WARNING: The web
>   process experienced a crash on ''.

So it seems that the webkit-related part of `qtdeclarative` still has some dependencies on `xcb`, that is on `x11`... why? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found a solution: I simply added `-qpa eglfs` to Qt configuration in Yocto. It seems to work.

Comment: Would you mind to specify where exactly this change should be done? It has been a while since you have find this solution though, I understand if you can't remember it.

Comment: @Isaac: in `qtbase.inc` you can change `PACKAGECONFIG[gles2] = "-opengl es2 -eglfs,,virtual/libgles2 virtual/egl"` to `PACKAGECONFIG[gles2] = "-opengl es2 -eglfs -qpa eglfs,,virtual/libgles2 virtual/egl"`; alternatively you can prepare a `qtbase_%.bbappend` file doing the same stuff